# Capybara 'Ambiguous matching link or button nil'

Tags: ruby, capybara

[inspecting web element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bof42.png)

[code to find element](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmlA0.png)

```
 def choose_ifp_term(ifp_term)
    if ifp_term == "Pay outright"
      Log.debug"Pay outright!"
    elsif ifp_term == "Interest Free 12 month"
      within page.first("div.tripleColumn") do
        page.find("div.device-payment-option-container").click_link_or_button(all("a").text.match(/#{ifp_term}/))
      end
      Log.debug"Found!"
    else
      Log.debug"Not Found!"
    end
  end
```

I've been trying to click an anchor tag that is nested in a div element, and Im trying to click 'x' element based on the arguement that I'm passing through.

I get an ***ambiguous*** match when trying to click the element based on the arguement.

> Ambiguous match, found 3 elements matching link or button nil (Capybara::Ambiguous)

The two images attached are the code and the element on the page. Please Help

SOLVED : with the help of @Tom

```
page.find("div.device-payment-option-container").find('a:nth-child(4)').click
```

As I could not find element based on regex argument passed, so had to click based on position!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`#all` returns an array like collection of elements, so calling `text` on it isn't valid and I'm not sure why that isn't raising an error for you.  Additionally, `#all` has a number of drawbacks (not waiting, not able to reload the found elements if they change, etc) and should be used only when absolutely necessary.  In your case where you appear to be looking for a link that matches a regex you can replace your use of `#all` with `#find`

```
find('a', text: /#{ifp_term}/)
```

so if using older Capybara all together it would be

```
page.find("div.device-payment-option-container").click_link_or_button(find('a', text: /#{ifp_term}/).text)
```

However if you're using Capybara 2.7 you should be able to do

```
page.find("div.device-payment-option-container").click_link_or_button(nil, text: /#{ifp_term}/)
```

and if using Capybara master which will become 2.8 you should be able to just do

```
page.find("div.device-payment-option-container").click_link_or_button(text: /#{ifp_term}/)
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of putting in "nil" as an argument. But i was still having trouble finding a link matching my regex /#{ifp_term} - so instead because I know the position. Im trying to click the second element by 
" page.find("div.device-payment-option-container").click_link_or_button(nil, count: 2)" but that doesnt work. 
also tried ".click_link_or_button(nil)[2].click but does not work either..?? thoughts

Comment: Solved ! by 

page.find("div.device-payment-option-container").find('a:nth-child(4)').click

Comment: I'm glad you got it working, but using positional selectors like that can lead to highly brittle tests.  If you can get the regex matching text argument working it would be better - your example picture doesnt actually show the contents of the link that would match the "Interest Free 12 month" text though

Comment: Ah yeah I understand. Actually I've just tried modifying my code to click the element based on the regexpression that ive passed through, and it WORKS! . And thats true it does make it brittle based on clicking by position . thanks for the help